# Render a Vue app using a promise, and await user input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I have a design question, I currently have a logic heavy JS script, which I have written as various promises and created a structure as the below:

```
init()
    .then(result => doSomethingA(result)) 
    .then(result => doSomethingB(result))
    .then(result => loadVueApp(result))
```

Now the `loadVueApp()` function calls does the following:

```
new Vue({
  el : '#app',
  render : h => h(App)
});
```

Which renders my Vue app, and then the user can interact with the app, go to various screens, make selections which I store in a global `EventBus` type component.

Now my question is, how should I pass the users choices back to my tower of promises? Should I be doing that at all?

I could resolve the `loadVueApp` right away based on simply the app appearing and then later make a function call back to the logic heavy script - but this does not feel as clean.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to pass data back to the *promise chain* unless `loadVueApp` resolves only after a choice was made and the Vue component destroyed? (Is that the case? Otherwise why would you be chaining the promises in series like that?)

Comment: yes, this is what I wanted to do - keep the promise unresolved until the user makes a selection and the app is closed.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple example which does the following:

- The Vue component is instantiated from a template and appended to the `<body>` element, rather than from an existing DOM element (in case you don't want the UI to be initially visible).
- The promise is only resolved with the inputted text when the submit button is clicked. The component instance is destroyed and removed from the DOM.

```js
const InputUI = {
  template: '#input-ui',
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
    };
  },
};

function getInput() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const inputUI = new Vue(InputUI);
    
    inputUI.$once('submit', value => {
      inputUI.$destroy();
      inputUI.$el.remove();
      resolve(value);
    });
    
    inputUI.$mount();
    document.body.appendChild(inputUI.$el);
  });
}

getInput().then(value => alert(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<template id="input-ui">
  <div>
    <input v-model="value">
    <button @click="$emit('submit', value)">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

If you're using single file components, you would structure your code similar to this:

**InputUI.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="value">
    <button @click="$emit('submit', value)">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
    };
  },
};

</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import InputUI from './InputUI.vue';

function getInput() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const InputUIVue = Vue.extend(InputUI);
    const inputUI = new InputUIVue();

    inputUI.$once('submit', value => {
      inputUI.$destroy();
      inputUI.$el.remove();
      resolve(value);
    });

    inputUI.$mount();
    document.body.appendChild(inputUI.$el);
  });
}

getInput().then(value => alert(value));
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it looks good - but this requires manual compilation or using the render function. I am using single file components.

Comment: I'm not using render functions, there's nothing about my example that can't be translated to single file components.

Comment: From Docs: `However, if you are relying on mounting to an element with existing content as template (using the el option), you will still be subject to those limitations.` I would like to avoid adding the compiler if possible or am I missing something?

Comment: The only reason why my answer is written in that way is to make it runnable online. To make it a single file component, all you have to do is put the `<template>` and component definition code into a .vue file as normal (and remove `template: '#input-ui'`). Everything else stays the same.

Comment: Hmm sorry @Decade Moon , not sure what I am doing wrong : `- Component template requires a root element, rather than just text.` But also if I remove the reference to the `template`, how will the call to `new Vue()` know where to get the HTML from?

Comment: You might need to instantiate `Vue.extend(InputUI)` because of the way `vue-loader` builds the component.